# Scopus Abstract Retrieval - Value and Type Error only when too many entries are parsed

Tags: python, scopus, pybliometrics

I am trying to retrieve abstracts via Scopus Abstract Retrieval. I have a file with 3590 EIDs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Amanda\Desktop\Superset.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

from pybliometrics.scopus import AbstractRetrieval
for i, row in file.iterrows():
  q = row['EID']
  ab = AbstractRetrieval(q,view='META_ABS')
  file.at[i,"Abstract"] = ab.description
  print(str(i) + ' ' + ab.description)
  print(str(''))
```

I get a value error - [image: Value Error]

In response to the value error, I altered the code.

```
from pybliometrics.scopus import AbstractRetrieval
error_index_valueerror = {}

    for i, row in file.iterrows():
      q = row['EID']
      try:
        ab = AbstractRetrieval(q,view='META_ABS')
        file.at[i,"Abstract"] = ab.description
        print(str(i) + ' ' + ab.description)
        print(str(''))
      except ValueError:
        print(f"{i} Value Error")
        error_index_valueerror[i] = row['Title']
        continue
```

When I trialed this code with 10-15 entries, it worked well and I retrieved all the abstracts. However, when I ran the actual file with 3590 EIDs, the output would be a series of 10-12 value errors before a type error ('can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str surfaces.

[image: Series of value errors and a type error]

I am not sure how to tackle this problem moving forward. Any advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

(Side note: When I change view='FULL' (as recommended by the documentation), I still get the same outcome.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without EIDs to check, it is tough to point to the precise cause. However, I'm 99% certain that your problem are missing abstracts in the `.description` property. It's sufficient when the first call is empty, because it will turn the column type into `float`, to which you wish to append a string. That's what the error says.

Thus your problem has nothing to do with pybliometrics or Scopus, but with the way you bild the code.

Try this instead:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pybliometrics.scopus import AbstractRetrieval

def parse_abstract(eid):
    """Retrieve Abstract of a document."""
    ab = AbstractRetrieval(q, view='META_ABS')
    return ab.description or ab.abstract


FNAME = r'C:\Users\Amanda\Desktop\Superset.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(FNAME, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df["abstract"] = df["EID"].apply(parse_abstract)
```

Instead of appending values one-by-one in a loop, which is slow and error-prone, I use pandas' `.apply()` methods.

Also note how I write `ab.description or ab.abstract`. https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes/AbstractRetrieval.html states that both should yield the same but can be empty. With this statement, if `ab.description` is empty (i.e., falsy), it will use `ab.abstract` instead.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error. Now, I understand why I get those error messages. Appreciate your help with the more robust code.